# React-Native: Can't receive expo push notification on stand alone app

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]**This is ss from standalone app, its gettings expo token but for some reason it wont show notifications**

I can't receive push notification on my standalone apps and if someone else used the app from expo (not my phone) then he won't receive it either, 
For some reason only i receive it ..that too on expo client and if i install the apk on my phone, then i get the error....
In these all situations the error is same,

```
{
"data": {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "SNS failed to send the notification (reason: EndpointDisabled, status code: 400).",
    "details": {
        "error": "DeviceNotRegistered",
        "sns": {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "reason": "EndpointDisabled",
            "__message": "Endpoint is disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

}

my notification js

```
 import { Permissions, Notifications } from 'expo';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  IUSTCONNECT_URL
} from '../actions/types';
const server = IUSTCONNECT_URL;
export default async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
    Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
  );
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
  // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
    // install, so this will only ask on iOS
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }

  // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
  let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
  console.log(token);


  await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationToken', token);
  const adminFlag = await AsyncStorage.getItem('admin');

  try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`${server}/admin/app_bridge/user.php`, {
      job: 'updateExpoToken',
      admin: adminFlag,
      token: token
    });
    if(data.trim() === 'success') {
            console.log('expo push notification token sent:');
    } else {
          console.log('error sending notification token:');
          console.log(data);
    }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
}
```

and i am calling `registerForPushNotificationsAsync()` on my child tab,
Everything works well for my expo app...rest it doesn't...
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the device. you can see in error `DeviceNotRegistered`.

[see expo docs here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html#devicenotregistered-the-device-cannot-receive-push-notifications-anymore-and-you-should-stop-sending-messages-to-the-given-expo-push-token).

> DeviceNotRegistered: the device cannot receive push notifications
>   anymore and you should stop sending messages to the given Expo push
>   token.

The problem is that in docs no information why this error is happening. Try with some other device's.

Answer (score 0):

if you develop with firebase you need update your token, the steps are:

1 in your page of project firebase, select option setting.
2 navigate to option project settings.
3 select option cloud messasging.
4 on credetial of project copy the token.
5. in your terminal in root directory of project type:

```
expo push:android:upload --api-key <your token>
```

for more information visit
[enter link description here](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/)

try send push notification Manually
[enter link description here](https://expo.io/notifications)

i'm working with sdk 37.0.0